# Can you run `geth inspect` while geth is running?

Tags: go-ethereum

I'd like to get some of the info provided by `geth inspect`, but it complains about a lock when I try running it, presumably because geth is indeed currently running.

```
$ geth inspect
...
Fatal: Failed to create the protocol stack: datadir already used by another process
```

I would be fine stopping geth for a few minutes, but [it appears from log messages](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14647#issuecomment-725740727) that it can take around 30 minutes:

```
INFO [11-11|19:19:35.100] Inspecting database                      count=4996000 elapsed=8.002s
INFO [11-11|19:19:43.108] Inspecting database                      count=10062000 elapsed=16.010s
INFO [11-11|19:19:51.115] Inspecting database                      count=14730000 elapsed=24.017s
...
INFO [11-11|19:50:53.083] Inspecting database                      count=1821919000 elapsed=31m25.985s
INFO [11-11|19:51:01.090] Inspecting database                      count=1828550000 elapsed=31m33.992s
INFO [11-11|19:51:09.097] Inspecting database                      count=1835247000 elapsed=31m41.999s
```

For my personal use case, I'm not able to stop my geth node for more than a few minutes without potentially incurring eth2 penalties.

But more importantly, it seems like an inspection should be able to be done live, since it's presumably a read-only action. Right?

Comment: since the database is being written by another process, there are protection mechanisms to access the DB. You could bypass this only by modifying sources

Comment: @Nulik So a feature request? What database tech does geth use under-the-hood?

Comment: LevelDB from Google